# How can we find count of element using selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

1. Navigate to http://www.ksrtc.in/
2. Search bus from Banglore to Tirupati for any date
3. in result page i don't get any count of bus.

Now I want to get number of bus from result page. 
How can we find count using selenium web driver?

Comment: what code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems awfully localized but here's how it goes.

Firstly you need to analyze the structure of the table containing the data, in your case, the result table containing the data does not have an ID which is not that great, but the div containing the table does so we have to work from that.

So naturally you retrieve the div first:

```
WebElement tableContainer = driver.findElement(By.id("table-container"));
```

Upon inspecting the contents of the div we see that it has multiple tables but also other things so lets parse out the tables first.

```
List<WebElement> allTables = tableContainer.findElements(By.tagName("table"));
```

Now that we have all of the tables we also know that the table we need does not have an ID and the other table has an ID of "table-1" so let's filter it out based on those facts.

```
WebElement resultTable = null;
for(WebElement table : allTables) {
    if("table-1".equalsIgnoreCase(table.getAttribute("id")){
        continue;
    }
    resultTable = table;
    break;
}
```

We then can retrieve the rows of the result table.

```
List<WebElement> resultRows = resultTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

**BUT WAIT!** The result table also contains a lot of useless rows that are not actually results. So let's anchor onto something that actually is present in the result rows e.g. the TD element with the class name "avaiTableHeaderA" containing the time of departure.

```
List<WebElement> trueResultRows = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
for(WebElement row : resultRows) {
    List<WebElement> rowDataElements = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    for(WebElement rowData : rowDataElements) {
        if("avaiTableHeaderA".equalsIgnoreCase(rowData.getAttribute("class"))){
            trueResultRows.add(row);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now that you have all of the actual result rows in a list you can just call:

```
trueResultRows.size()
```

to get the amount of results returned, or to perform various operations on the rows themselves like extracting specific data like departure/arrival times etc.